# Return false only if count is 0

Tags: php, sql, select, return

I am trying to make sure that my function return `false` only if `count` for `cc` is `0`. I keep getting `false` back from my function even when `count` is more than `0`.

My function:

```
function db_cc_exists($link, $cc) {
  $sql = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM visitors WHERE cc = '$cc' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $ret = $row[0];

  mysqli_free_result($result);
  return (intval($ret) == 0 ? FALSE : TRUE);
}
```

`$link` is the connection of my database.

Comment: @bansi sorry updated it. I was just testing what I will get from it. Count is also a column in my table

Comment: What is `$cc`? Have you checked for errors already? I'm not sure you can use an alias name that is also a column name..

Comment: cc is a column in my table which is country. Basically, I am checking if country has a visitor already from it. @chris85

Comment: Yea, I'm not asking what `cc` is; what is `$cc`. If it contains a quote this query will fail (unless you escaped earlier?).

Comment: print_r($row );exit(); and say what it is returning?

Comment: $cc corresponds directly to the value in the database and I double checked if it correct @chris85

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ret ($row[0]) is an array. Use $ret['count']

```
return (intval($ret['count']) == 0 ? FALSE : TRUE);
```

**UPDATE**

I believe my original answer is actually incorrect.

mysqli_fetch_array takes 2 parameters - the second is the type of array to return. The default is MYSQLI_BOTH which creates an array with both numeric indexes (in your case with element '0') and associative indexes (in your case 'count').

`$row[0];` should have returned the count.

The options for the 2nd parameter

```
/* numeric array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);

/* associative array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

/* associative and numeric array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

If you followed my original answer and used `intval($ret['count']`, you should have received the error "Illegal string offset 'count'".

A simple test is to put a `var_dump($row)` statement after it is set to see what is being returned.

You should get something like:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "123" ["count"]=> string(5) "123" }
```

Comment: Works... exactly what I was looking for. Can you put an explanation on this?

Comment: I've updated my answer, but my answer should have been incorrect. I am not really sure why you original code did not work. Put a `var_dump($row)` statement after `$row` is set to see what is being returned.

Answer (score 1):

Your query returns either any value from `0` to number of records. So try condition like this.

Please try to check like this.

```
function db_cc_exists($link, $cc) {
  $sql = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM visitors WHERE cc = '$cc' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);    
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  return ($row[0] ? TRUE : FALSE);
}
```

Comment: Sure, up to you. I'm just pointing out that answers should contain an explanation of what is happening. If 5 people were to answer this question I wouldnt expect the OP to try all 5 answers just because they said `try this`..

Comment: @chris85 I knew, but let me breath and add something!!